# C# RegEx: Ignore case... in pattern?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm using System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(testString, regexPattern) to do some searches in strings.

Is there a way to specify in the regexPattern string that the pattern should ignore case? (I.e. without using Regex.IsMatch(testString, regexPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))

Answer (score 166, accepted):

`(?i)` within the pattern begins case-insensitive matching, `(?-i)` ends it. That is,

```
(?i)foo(?-i)bar
```

matches `FOObar`, `fOobar` and `foobar` but **not** `fooBAR`.

**EDIT:** I should have said `(?-i)` starts case-sensitive matching - if you want the whole pattern to be case-insensitive then you don't need to "end" the `(?i)`.

Comment: Is the ending (?-i) required or can it be omitted?

Comment: BTW, this syntax also works in regex libraries from other languages such as Java and Scala.

Comment: @DanielK given your edit, it reads that (?-i) *starts* case sensitive matching.  Per the example, (?-i) *ends* case sensitive matching.  Am I missing something? Is the example wrong?

Comment: @danjuggler In the example, `(?-i)` *ends* case-**in**sensitive matching. In other words, `(?-i)` *starts* case-sensitive matching. In the original edit by stevemegson, he said it *begins* case-sensitive matching, which was also correct.

Comment: this works as advertised.