# How can Python regex ignore case inside a part of a pattern but not the entire expression?

Tags: python, regex, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

Say I have a string containing `foobar fooBAR FOObar FOOBAR`, and I want to search all instances containing a case insensitive "foo" or "FOO" *but* a lowercase "bar". In this case, `re.findall` should return `['foobar', 'FOObar']`.

The accepted answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583678/c-regex-ignore-case-in-pattern) explains that it can be done in C# with `(?i)foo(?-i)bar`, but Python raises an invalid expression error.

Does the Python regex library support such a feature?

Comment: @Donal Fellows: Yes, that is possible as well, but not as common as purely uppercase or purely lowercase "foo"s in my application. A possibility would be to implement a less-than-perfect solution and test for just those two cases.

Comment: The answers are no longer valid for Python 3.6 and later as `re` now supports inline modifier groups.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The re module doesn't support scoped flags, but there's an alternative regex implementation which does:

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex

Answer (score 7):

Python does not support disabling flags in the same manner; you will have to handle it differently.

```
>>> re.match('[Ff][Oo]{2}bar', 'Foobar')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7eff94dac920>
```

Comment: I was fearing that solution, but it may work. In application, "foo" (the case insensitive part) will be replaced by an arbitrary string, escaped by `re.escape`. Thus, I would need to expand the string programmatically to `'[' + s[i] + s[i].swapcase() + ']' ...`. Possible punctuation and other non-alphanumeric characters would create a problem however.