# Create validation for CSV and Text file only (case insenstive)

Tags: c#, regex

I wants to upload file with extension .csv and .txt only and It would be case insensitive.

For example .csv, .CSV, .CsV, .txt, .tXt , .TxT ...

I am currently using this one

```
(?i)[.](csv|txt)
```

But its not work when the extension is case-sensitive.

Comment: What does your regex code look like?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583678/c-sharp-regex-ignore-case-in-pattern

Comment: But this one not works for client side validation

Comment: i see unnecesary downvote it only for being duplicate, with flag it's OK

Comment: how you doing client side validation? JavaScript?

Comment: @sandeepsinghwarring please explain much better what do you mean with *client-side*

Comment: @Damith if he is using javascript, the whole question it's wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This regex will help you in both client side and server side validation:

```
^.*\.([cC][sS][vV]|[tT][xX][tT]??)$
```

if you want atleast one character as name (before .txt or .csv) then following will help:

```
^.+\.([cC][sS][vV]|[tT][xX][tT]??)$
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to end it with (?-i), as such:

```
(?i)[.](csv|txt)(?-i)
```

Comment: That is only nessesary if you have more case sensitive charactors to match. If you don't include the `(?-i)` it simply doesn't change to case sensitive matching. Which I guess could be the problem, if he didn't include the whole regex pattern.

Comment: ah. you sir, are correct.